# Нужна помощь с декодированием Json flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

У меня есть несколько классов с toJson и fromJson. Проблема в том, что они содержаться в Folder.directoryChildrens и мне нужно в Folder.fromJson каждый класс как-то декодировать, чтобы все заработало. Есть варианты как это можно сделать?

```
class Folder {
  final String directoryName;
  final List directoryChildrens;
  Folder({
    required this.directoryName,
    required this.directoryChildrens,
  });

  Folder.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : directoryName = json['directoryName'],
        directoryChildrens = json['directoryChildrens'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'directoryName': directoryName,
        'directoryChildrens':
            directoryChildrens.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
      };
}


// Пример класса, который добавляется в Folder.directoryChildrens
class Chat {
  AllType type;
  String? name;
  bool animate;
  bool dublicated;
  bool link;
  bool pinned;
  List? messages;
  List? favorites;
  String pathToImage;

  Chat(
      {this.type = AllType.chat,
      this.name,
      this.animate = false,
      this.pinned = false,
      this.dublicated = false,
      this.link = false,
      this.favorites,
      this.pathToImage = '',
      this.messages});

  Chat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : type = AllType.values.elementAt(json['type']),
        name = json['name'],
        link = json['link'],
        pinned = json['pinned'],
        dublicated = json['dublicated'],
        animate = json['animate'],
        messages = json['messages'],
        pathToImage = json['pathToImage'],
        favorites = json['favorites'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'type': type.index,
      'name': name,
      'link': link,
      'pinned': pinned,
      'dublicated': dublicated,
      'animate': animate,
      'messages': messages!.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
      'pathToImage': pathToImage,
      'favorites': favorites
    };
  }
}

// еще один класс, который добавляется в Folder.directoryChildrens

class StorageFile {
  AllType type;
  String? name;
  String? data;
  List? history;
  bool dublicated;
  bool link;
  bool animate;
  bool pinned;
  String pathToImage;

  StorageFile(
      {this.type = AllType.storageFile,
      this.name,
      this.data,
      this.link = false,
      this.dublicated = false,
      this.pinned = false,
      this.pathToImage = '',
      this.history,
      this.animate = false});

  StorageFile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : type = AllType.values.elementAt(json['type']),
        name = json['name'],
        link = json['link'],
        dublicated = json['dublicated'],
        pinned = json['pinned'],
        data = json['data'],
        history = json['history'],
        pathToImage = json['pathToImage'],
        animate = json['animate'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'type': type.index,
        'name': name,
        'link': link,
        'dublicated': dublicated,
        'pinned': pinned,
        'data': data,
        'history': history,
        'animate': animate,
        'pathToImage': pathToImage
      };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, AllType указывает на тип конкретной модели. В таком случае следующее решение должно помочь:

```
directoryChildrens =
    (json['directoryChildrens'] as List<dynamic>).map<dynamic>((dynamic e) {
      switch(AllType.values.elementAt(e['type'])) {
        case AllType.chat:
          return Chat.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>);
        case AllType.storageFile:
          return StorageFile.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>);
      }
    }).toList();
```

Если же нет, то вам определенно нужно получать тип с сервера.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, ты мне очень помог. Это действительно работает